# Issue with Folium library in JupyterLab - Trusted Notebook Does not Show the Map

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, folium

I know the issue of trusting a python notebook has been previously discussed. I was just playing with the Folium library to create some maps and noted that the map is not showing as the notebook was deemed untrusted.

I followed all the instructions, and the maps are still not showing. Even the notebook itself, on the top right corner, says the .ipynb file is trusted:

[image]

So not quite sure what the issue might be. Any thoughts on that? Thanks!

Comment: Please, provide version for folium and jupyter. Thanks.

Comment: @sentence: I am using JupyterLab version 2.0.1 and folium version 0.5.0...thanks!

Comment: Both the packages are very outdated. Maybe updating them could solve the problem.

Comment: Just updated the JupyterLab to 2.1.4 and folium to 0.11.0, which are the latest versions. And it doesn't seem to be working. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: What about the browser? Have you tried with mozilla?

Comment: Thanks, @sentence! You got it right! The browser was the issue...actually Anaconda Navigator automatically opened JupyterLab in Microsoft Edge, I just changed my default browser to Google Chrome, and it is now working. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a [well](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/629)-[known](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/1329) problem.

Opening Jupyter on Firefox (or Chrome) should solve your problem.